# How do I consume a WCF service that receives a strongly-typed object as input?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I'm a newbie with WCF. I just followed a simple walkthrough to create and consume a simple WCF service (the walkthrough uses a string data type). However, I'm not able to consume a WCF service with a custom type. Here's what I tried:

First, I created the interface.

```
[DataContract]
    public class TicketInfo
    {
        public string TicketID { get; set; }
        public string TicketDescription { get; set; }
    }

    [OperationContract]
    String GetTicketInfo(TicketInfo ticketInfo);
```

I then created the method in the service that implements the interface:

```
public string GetTicketInfo(TicketInfo ticketInfo)
{
    return string.Format("The ID is {0}", ticketInfo.TicketID);
}
```

I then added the Service Reference on the client.

Now, I'm trying to consume the service:

```
    Service1Client client = new Service1Client();

        string returnString;
        TicketInfo ticketInfo = new TicketInfo();
        ticketInfo.ID = "1";
        returnString = client.GetTicketInfo(ticketInfo);
```

The code fails here:

> ```
>         ticketInfo.TicketID = "1";
> ```

The error message is:

> 'Ticketnfo' does not contain a definition for 'TicketID' and no extension
>   method 'TicketID' accepting a first argument of type 'TicketInfo' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Going to the definition of TicketInfo on the client shows:

```
public partial class TicketInfo : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

[System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

[global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
    get {
        return this.extensionDataField;
    }
    set {
        this.extensionDataField = value;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't ServiceReference1.TicketInfo on the client have all the properties of Service1.TicketInfo on the server? How can I consume the service?

Comment: You have a property TicketID, and you try to access it with ID. Maybe update the service reference

Comment: or use TicketID...

Comment: Try decorating the members of the DataContract  with the `DataMember` attribute

Comment: @[Servé Laurijssen] Sorry about that. That as a typo. While trying to simplify the code for posting, I spelled it wrong. The property name is the same on the server.

Comment: @[Ashley John] Thank you! That's what I missed. Could you please post the same as an answer so that I can accept and close this?

Comment: @Zesty Added . Glad to help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try decorating the members of the DataContract with the DataMember attribute